# How to specify the " character

Tags: c#, html, winforms

I am trying to use string.Remove to remove all occurrences of " in my html, but I forgot how to tell it to use " as a character instead of its usual meaning.

Thanks.

Comment: `str.Replace(CChar(""""), "")` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to escape it with `\`, so write `\"` instead of `"` where you mean `"`.

string.Remove removed part of the string based on start index, and length, so that is not what you are actually looking for, but replace will help you to get rid of all `"`'s.

```
myString.Replace("\"","")
```

Comment: Yes sorry, was using replace in my code just mistyped it here.

Answer (score 2):

```
\"
```

Simply escape the quotes with a backslash.

Answer (score 2):

You should escape the `"` character by using a slash: `\"`:

```
string newString = myHtml.Replace("\"", string.Empty)
```

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to escape chars in most environments is with a backslash.

So you're looking for `\"`.

Answer (score 1):

you can also write

```
&#34;
```

to display " characters in html